# Django URL redirect all PHP requests

Tags: php, python, django, .htaccess, redirect

How can I redirect all requests containing `PHP` anywhere in the url?

I have this to redirect anything ending with `.php`

```
url(r'^(?P<path>.*)\.php$', 
    RedirectView.as_view(
        url='http://www.php.net/', permanent=True)),
```

Now, I want to catch and redirect all url requests containing the keyword `php` anywhere in the url even without the dot `.` something like `blah/php/blah` or `blahPHPblah` etc.

Something like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<path>php*)', 
    RedirectView.as_view(
        url='http://blah.com/', permanent=True)),
```

If .htaccess rule would be a better solution, I'm open to that as well!

Comment: do you have these paths in the same webapp?

Comment: Just the first one, and that is working OK, when I was trying to add the second one (after the first one) to catch all `php`, it would not work.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use redirect middleware:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


class PHPRedirectMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        if ".php" in request.get_raw_uri():
            return redirect(to="http://www.example.com")

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response
```

Which you have to register in the `settings.py` in the `MIDDLEWARE` list.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a shot. BTW, what would be the best way to include other keywords such, `cgi`, `wordpress` etc?

Comment: @WayBehind well depends, do you want to redirect all of them to a single URL or each one to a different URL? If it's a single one, I would make a setting like `REDIRECT_TRIGGERS = ["bla", "foo"]` and then in the middleware I would import the settings from `django.conf` and do `if any([trigger in request.get_raw_uri() for trigger in settings.REDIRECT_TRIGGERS])`

Comment: @WayBehind but if it's a map, then you need a dict setting, with each trigger specifying either the full path or a named path, which are resolved dynamically in the middleware.

Comment: my web is bombarded with a lots of spammy requests and I'm just trying to put in place something that will stop triggering 404 and 500 when under attack. And most of those requests have `php` or `cgi` in the URL.